# Why the path that is in application.properties changes when dockerizing the application?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a small application that writes and reads files from a given path. The path is located into the `application.properties`:

```
application:
  base-folder: /home
```

When I start the docker container, instead of having `/home`, it simply changes to `/home/folder` and I cannot figure out why.
The flow is like this:

```
@DeleteMapping(path = "/folder/{folderName}")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
public void deleteFolder(@PathVariable("folderName") String folderName) {
    mediaFacade.deleteFolder(folderName);
}
```

Then the method in the `mediaFacade` is called and delegates the `folderName` to a service calling this:

```
public void deleteFolder(String folder) throws IOException {
    FileUtils.deleteDirectory(new File(applicationBaseFolder + SLASH + folder));
}
```

The stacktrace is this:

```
codetech-media  | java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /home/folder/Java 103
codetech-media  |       at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:86) ~[na:1.8.0_302]
codetech-media  |       at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102) ~[na:1.8.0_302]
codetech-media  |       at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107) ~[na:1.8.0_302]
codetech-media  |       at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.implDelete(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:244) ~[na:1.8.0_302]
codetech-media  |       at sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.delete(AbstractFileSystemProvider.java:103) ~[na:1.8.0_302]
codetech-media  |       at java.nio.file.Files.delete(Files.java:1126) ~[na:1.8.0_302]
codetech-media  |       at com.ucv.media.service.FileService.deleteFile(FileService.java:59) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
codetech-media  |       at com.ucv.media.facade.MediaFacade.deleteFile(MediaFacade.java:66) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
codetech-media  |       at com.ucv.media.controller.MediaController.deleteMedia(MediaController.java:65) [classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
codetech-media  |       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_302]
codetech-media  |       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_302]
codetech-media  |       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_302]
codetech-media  |       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_302]
codetech-media  |       at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197) [spring-web-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
codetech-media  |       at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141) [spring-web-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
codetech-media  |       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) [spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
codetech-media  |       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) [spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
codetech-media  |       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) [spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
codetech-media  |       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) [spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
codetech-media  |       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1064) [spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
codetech-media  |       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) [spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
codetech-media  |       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) [spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
codetech-media  |       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doDelete(FrameworkServlet.java:931) [spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
codetech-media  |       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar!/:na]
codetech-media  |       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) [spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
codetech-media  |       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar!/:na]
codetech-media  |       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar!/:na]
codetech-media  |       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar!/:na]
codetech-media  |       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) [tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.52.jar!/:na]
codetech-media  |       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar!/:na]
codetech-media  |       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar!/:na]
codetech-media  |       at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) [spring-web-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
codetech-media  |       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
codetech-media  |       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar!/:na]
codetech-media  |       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar!/:na]
codetech-media  |       at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) [spring-web-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
codetech-media  |       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
codetech-media  |       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar!/:na]
codetech-media  |       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar!/:na]
codetech-media  |       at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) [spring-web-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
codetech-media  |       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
codetech-media  |       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar!/:na]
codetech-media  |       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar!/:na]
codetech-media  |       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar!/:na]
codetech-media  |       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar!/:na]
codetech-media  |       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar!/:na]
codetech-media  |       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar!/:na]
codetech-media  |       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar!/:na]
codetech-media  |       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar!/:na]
codetech-media  |       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar!/:na]
codetech-media  |       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar!/:na]
codetech-media  |       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar!/:na]
codetech-media  |       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar!/:na]
codetech-media  |       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1726) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar!/:na]
codetech-media  |       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar!/:na]
codetech-media  |       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar!/:na]
codetech-media  |       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar!/:na]
codetech-media  |       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar!/:na]
codetech-media  |       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_302]
```

If I am no longer using the Docker, and just running the application with a Windows path, it does its job, but using the Docker, it simply does not does its job.

Comment: How is `applicationPropertiesBaseFolder` defined and what exactly do you mean by dockerizing. I mean how do you make your application run in Docker

Comment: it can not change as you say it changes. One possible scenario could be that you have defined an environment variable during docker build that defines application.base-folder with /home/folder

Comment: I solved the problem... that FileUtils was a method from a library that I was using to zip files. I did not know that until I entered inside of it and saw that. Somehow, it was adding that `/folder` to my `/home`. By dockerizing I was meaning that I make a simple Dockerfile with a docker-compose.yml. The value was correctly injected: ```@Value("${application.base-folder}")``` . Right now I am using `commons-io` to delete the file.